# Can not use translate() method in xpath with lxml etree

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I want to use translate to lower my text with lxml library in Python. My code is as below

```
r = element.xpath('./a/translate(text(), "A", "a")')
```

But it give me an exception:

```
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

I'd like to do this with xpath only (without writing code in Python). Please give me a solution. Thanks

Comment: Your syntax is valid in XPath 2.0 but not in XPath 1.0, let alone in the subset of XPath 1.0 supported by ElementTree. Other XPath processors are available for Python (for example SaxonC supports XPath 3.1).

Comment: There is also https://github.com/sissaschool/elementpath for XPath 2, 3.0 and 3.1 evaluation on element trees in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try following code by wrapping up the translate outside

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '''<root>
    <a>A TEXT CONTENT</a>
</root>'''

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
element = root.xpath('translate(./a/text(), "A", "a")')
print(element)
```

Result

```
a TEXT CONTENT
```

You can also specify more translation rules

```
element = root.xpath('translate(./a/text(), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")')
```

Result

```
a text content
```